# Jersey Client download ZIP file and unpack efficiently

Tags: java, rest, jersey, zip

So, I have a server application that returns ZIP files and I'm working with huge files (>=5GB). I am then using the jersey client to do a GET request from this application after which I want to basically extract the ZIP and save it as a folder. This is the client configuration:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
client.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
return client;
```

And here's the code fetching the response from the server:

```
client.target(subMediumResponseLocation).path("download?delete=true").request()
                                           .get().readEntity(InputStream.class)
```

My code then goes through a bunch of (unimportant for this question) steps and finally gets to the writing of data.

```
try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(inputStream)) {
   ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
   while(ze != null){
     String fileName = ze.getName();
     if(fileName.contains(".")) {
       size += saveDataInDirectory(folder,zis,fileName);
     }
     is.closeEntry();
     ze = zis.getNextEntry();
  }
  zis.closeEntry();
} finally {
  inputStream.close();
}
```

Now the issue I'm getting is that the ZipInputStream refuses to work. I can debug the application and see that there are bytes in the InputStream but when it get to the `while(ze != null)` check, it returns null on the first entry, resulting in an empty directory.

I have also tried writing the InputStream from the client to a ByteArrayOutputStream using
the `transferTo` method, but I get a java heap space error saying the array length is too big (even though my heap space settings are Xmx=16gb and Xms=12gb).

My thoughts were that maybe since the InputStream is lazy loaded by `Jersey` using the `UrlConnector` directly, this doesn't react well with the `ZipInputStream`. Another possible issue is that I'm not using a `ByteArrayInputStream` for the `ZipInputStream`.

What would a proper solution for this be (keeping in mind the heap issues)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved it, apparently my request was getting a 404 for adding the query param in the path... `.path("download?delete=true")`